# Migrate Azure VM from US to Europe

Tags: azure, migration

What is the easiest way to move a Azure VM from US to Europe?
Azure Site Recovery is not an option because US and Europe is not in the same geographical cluster.

The Azure VM I want to move has unmanaged disks so my current runbook is like this:

1. Shutdown VM in US and copy the vhds to a storage account in Europe
2. Create Managed Disks in Europe from the Disks that were copied
3. Create a VM from managed OS Disk and attach managed data disks to VM
4. Boot VM with all attached disks

Is there a better way to approach this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the possiblity to run the VM's on premise for a short period?

If so you could use Azure Site Recovery to fail over to on premise servers. And then use Azure Site Recovery to fail over to Azure Europe.